# Unknown encoder 'libx264' .I am using x264 and fdk-aac with avconv from libav

Tags: software-installation

I did the following:

1. Make a directory avconv-source

   ```
   mkdir avconv-source
   ```
2. Download and install the x264 library

   ```
   cd ~/avconv-source git clone git://git.videolan.org/x264.git x264
   cd x264
   sudo ./configure --enable-static
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```
3. Download the avconv source

   ```
   cd ~/avconv-source git clone git://git.libav.org/libav.git avconv
   cd avconv
   sudo ./configure
   sudo ./configure --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
   sudo make
   sudo make install
   ```

Comment: If someone's answer was helpful to you, then please consider marking it as the [accepted answer](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer) so others may more easily find it in the future. This is also a polite way to thank the person answering your question for helping you out.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need all that.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libav-tools
```

This will install avconv as well.

Comment: Will this install fdk-aac as well and make it available to avconv?

Comment: Using a built-in package is different from compiling from source. It doesn't mean it's redundant. Compiling from source is the best way to get updated binaries.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get an up to date command-line encoder with access to x264 and fdk-aac (and a great deal more) is to use *FFmpeg* and the following guide:

[Compile FFmpeg on Ubuntu, Debian, or Mint](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Ubuntu)

As far as I am aware a similar guide does *not* exist for avconv / libav.